# What would be the "correct salute" for this sentence?

Tags: how-i-met-your-mother

Ted and Robin have [this running gag](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/Mock_Salutes), where they salute when words denoting ranks of military staff occur.
For example, if someone says

> That's a major problem.

They salute and say

> Major problem!

---

Now, imagine someone says like

> It's just tedious in general.

What do they respond? "General period!"?
Has this ever occured in any episode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not how the gag works. The point is to take someone saying "*Rank, word*" and salute it (as you would if you were in the army and were to encounter that person) not to construct sentences or salute single words.

**General Knowledge**

Comment: Where did I say they use it to construct sentences?

Comment: @cad - Above, in your question.

Comment: I cannot tell the difference between what they said in the clip and my example.

Comment: @cad - In your example, they would be saluting the rank on its own. The gag is that they subtract part of a clichéd phrase like as "it's a **private matter**" or "that's **general knowledge**" so that they're saluting **the person mentioned**.